# Exception, handler is not a function, serverless offline

Tags: node.js, rest, lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to make a rest api with Lambda and serverless framework. But getting this error

```
memberships/member is not a function
 at InProcessRunner.run (file:///home/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/InProcessRunner.js:60:13)
```

My `serverless.yml` looks like this:

```
 getmemberships:
    handler: memberships/member.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: memberships/get
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            name: verifyToken
            resultTtlInSeconds: 0
            identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
            type: token
```

And my `handler` looks like this

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
   return connectToDatabase()
     .then(() => currentUser(event.requestContext.authorizer.principalId))
     .then((user) => (
     await Membership.find({
        spaceId: user.spaceId
       }).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    ).then((response)=> ({
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(response),
    })))
    .catch((err) => ({
      statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
      body: { stack: err.stack, message: err.message },
    }));
};
```

Comment: Solved this after hours of debugging, its really a vague error, at first it seemed like export issue but it wasn't. i had some other issue in my code, for better error logs you can invoke a single function at a time locally with this `serverless invoke local --function functionName`